# How can I subset a variable based on its percentile when using logistic regression

Tags: r, subset, logistic-regression

I have a line of code that calculates logistic regression based on 2 variables where one variable's values are above its mean:

```
ff <- lrm(Target ~  var1 + , data = dat ,subset = var1>=mean(var1))
```

I would like to change the `mean` to a percentile: for example do the subset on observations where the value of `var1` is higher than the 7th percentile and less than the 9th percentile.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

```
ff <- lrm( Target ~  var1 + , data = dat ,subset=var1>=quantile(var1, 0.07) & var1<=quantile(var1, 0.09))
```